# Connecting to an open TCP(Telnet) stream / JAVA

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, telnet, tcpclient

I was wondering if it is possible to connect a Socket to "listen" (at least, maybe write, too, if possible) to an active telnet connection run by another program.
As I understand, this should be possible, as there are programs like Wireshark that can read from open connections.
So my question is how this is done with java. Do I just connect a Socket on the same port (doubtedly)?

Answer (score -1):

Wireshark uses libpcap library from tcpdump to capture packets: https://www.tcpdump.org/

There are Java bindings for libpcap: https://www.pcap4j.org/

Comment: Oh, great, thanks for the quick answer, and can I actually write to that open stream using pcap?

Comment: @user207421 Actually this question should be closed for *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. *